# Is this a valid inequality formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

If $a > b$ and $c > d$ then $ac > bd$ provided $a, b, c, d$ are all **positive real**
?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This holds because $ac>bc>bd$. Alternatively, we have $ac>ad>bd$.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that $$ac-bd=ac-bc+bc-bd=(a-b)c+b(c-d)>0$$ thus  $$ac>bd$$

Comment: How did you get from $(a-b)c + b(c-d) > 0$ to getting $ac > bc$?

Comment: Because $ac-bd\ge0$ is the same as $ac\ge bd$.

Comment: it should be either `>` or $\ge$ on both lines, I believe.

Comment: @Mico, how is $ac - bc > 0$ proven?

Comment: @Amad27 I hope you mean how is $ac-bd>0$ proven, right? I wrote $ac-bd$ as some of two positive numbers that's why it is positive

Comment: -$-bd < 0$ thought

Comment: @Amad27 - By assumption, the four numbers are positive and $a>b$ and $c>d$. Hence $a-b>0$ and $c-d>0$, and therefore also $(a-b)c+b(c-d)>0$. (Do you maybe need a proof of the claim that products of positive numbers are also positive?) Simplifying this expression gives you $ac-bd>0$, which is the same as $ac>bd$.

Comment: Yeah, I was very tired when I read this; apologies, I could have understood it if I tried harder. thanks though @Mico

Answer (score 0):

Here's still another demonstration.

By assumption, the four real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are positive, and $a>b$ and $c>d$. We can re-express the inequalities as $a=b+u$ and $c=d+v$ for some positive real numbers $u$ and $v$. Thus, $$ac=(b+u)(d+v)=bd+bv+ud+uv>bd$$ because $bv$, $ud$, and $uv$ are all positive (they're products of positive numbers).